# How can I setup go-gb to build inside of vim

Tags: vim, go

Has anyone setup go-gb as your makeprg in vim?  There is all sorts of documentation on configuration makeprg for compiling c code, but now much that I can find on configuring new commands.

Ideally i'd be able to run the :make command from vim and utilize errorformat on my builds.

```
set errorformat=%D(in\ %.%#)\ building\ pkg\ \"%f\",%f:%l:\ %m%.%#,%-G%.%#
```

Comment: What went wrong when you used this errorformat? Something similar worked for me.

Comment: The error format isn't what's wrong, I stole that from somewhere else.  The problem is I don't know the syntax of the makeprg command, so I'm not sure how to set it up with gb.  I assume that if I get it running correctly, this errorformat will work fine.  Right now that way I have gb setup it seems to be trying to build my entire home diretory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `gb` as your `makeprg` in `vim`:

```
$ cd mygodir
$ vi main.go
#inside vi
# :set errorformat=%D(in\ %.%#)\ building\ pkg\ \"%f\",%f:%l:\ %m%.%#,%-G%.%#
#and then
# :set makeprg=gb
#now
#:mak
#will work as usual.
```

Comment: Thats fine if you are working from the terminal, then I'm assuming gb inherits the current working direction from where vim was executed, but what I'm looking for is to setup makeprg to run in the current working directory of the file that is open.

Comment: How do you do that with standard make? It's not a go related quetion, it's vi related question. Can't you :cd to the current directory, or at least make a command that automatically `:cd %:p:h`

Comment: That's a good question.  It may not be possible.  I did find the vim project plugin which does an automatic CD to the project directory making it ideal for use with any makeprg setup.  I think that's what I'll go with.